# Julia Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, julia, string-literals

I'm trying to compare two lists and would like to use regular expression to do just that. Accordingly, I'd like to loop through the elements of one list and compare it to each of the elements in the other list. I can't seem to figure out how to make my regular expression contain a variable. Hopefully, this code should elucidate the matter:

```
string1="chase"

string2="chasecb"

m=match(r"$string1"  ,string2)

println(m)
```

I know that the $ is a regular expression metacharacter and I've tried escaping it and various permutations of that idea and so forth. Is there another way? Thanks so much.

Comment: here is one way:m=match(Regex(string1)  ,string2)

Comment: You can bypass the macro and use `Regex(string1)` or `Regex("$string1")` to interpolate into a regular expression.

Comment: we were only seconds apart.....what the difference between r and Regex?

Comment: It is well answered here: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#man-non-standard-string-literals2

Comment: But do you really need to use regexes?  If the search terms are always literal strings (e.g. `chase`), Julia string functions like `contains()`, `beginswith()` and `endswith()` should be all you need.

Answer (score 2):

As [jverzani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340844/jverzani) said in a comment, you can use `Regex(string1)` or `Regex("$string1")` to interpolate into a regular expression, for example:

```
string1 = "chase"
string2 = "chasecb"
m = match(Regex(string1), string2)
println(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need yo use the `Regex()` functions instead of `r`. For example:

```
string1="chase"

string2="chasecb"

m=match(r"$string1"  ,string2)

println(m)
```

For more details you can take a look at: [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.3/manual/strings/#Regular-Expressions-1)

Comment: the referenced doc requires authentication. also, your solution is exactly what chasecb posted in the question.